# is the group $(\mathbb{Z}_n \times \{-1,1\}, *) \simeq D_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

is the group $(\mathbb{Z}_n \times \{-1,1\}, *) \simeq D_n$

$*: (a,b) * (c,d) = (a+_n(c \cdot_n b),bd)$

Showing $(\mathbb{Z}_n \times \{-1,1\}, *)$ was a group was a previous question but I have shown it is associative, the identity is $(0,1)$ and the inverse is $(\frac{-a}{b}, \frac{1}{b})$ and $\frac{-a}{b}, \frac{1}{b} \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ because $b = \pm1$

$D_n = \langle r,f\rangle$ so the former group needs to be generated by two elements, if it were just $\mathbb{Z}_n$ then the generator would be $\langle 1 \rangle$ but seems that $(\mathbb{Z}_n \times \{-1,1\}, *) = \langle (1,-1), (-1,1), (1,1) \rangle$ being generated by 3 elements so I want to say false but maybe I am incorrect.

Comment: Just because a group has a set of three generators does *not* mean it doesn't also have a set of two generators. The elements $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$ are closely related. Look at powers of $(1,1)$.

Comment: $(1,1)*(1,1)=(2,1)$ and $(-1,1)*(-1,1)=(-2,1)$ and $(1,1)*(-1,1) = e = (-1,1)*(1,1)$ so we could have $\langle (1,-1), (1,1)\rangle = (\mathbb{Z}_n \times \{1,-1\}, *)$

but now the issue would be finding the map provides the isomorphism

Comment: OK, now *think* about it yourself some more.

Comment: the onto mapping isn't hard but 1-1 not so much. $\phi(a,b) = x, x \in D_n$ 
would need,
$\phi((1,-1)*(1,-1)) = f \circ f = e_{D_n} = \phi((1,-1)) \circ \phi((1,-1))$ because $f^2 = e \in D_n$ I must be overthinking this

Comment: Note that the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ can be expressed as the [semidirect product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product#Examples) $\mathbb{Z}_n \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: $\phi((1,-1))=f, \phi(1,1)=r$ then can build all the powers from these two. i.e. $\phi((1,-1)(1,1)(1,-1))=frf=r^{-1}$

@SpamIAm I will read the wiki page on that, we are supposed to do these problems without even knowing what the semi-product is

Comment: Forget semidirect products.  If they haven't been covered in the class then don't try that method.  Just write down a function from one group to the other, check it is a *homomorphism*, and then show either that it's inject or that it's surjective. Either property implies the other because both groups have the same (finite) size, namely $2n$.

Comment: @oliverjones You don't have to really know about semidirect products for the link to be useful.  The point is that while $D_n$ is *not* isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, it "almost" is in a precise way.  Anyway, if you were dealing with the $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, what generators would you choose?  Do these work for this case, too?

Comment: @SpamIAm seems the generators would be $\langle (1,0),(1,1) \rangle$ although I don't see that working because $ 0 \not\in \{-1,1\}$,  $D_n$ is built off of rotations and flips so the function mapping needs to take from an ordered pair to the flip or rotation or whatever combination of composition there is. so wouldn't the  mapping i gave above $\phi((1,-1))=f, \phi(1,1)=r$ work? But I gotta figure out how $\phi$ maps specifically

Comment: @oliverjones Why wouldn't you pick the generators for the respective factors, i.e., $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$?  And $\{-1, 1\}$ is just $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \{\overline{0}, \overline{1}\}$ written multiplicatively.

Comment: @KCd I'm only coming up with how to map the generators to the generators. $f \neq r^k$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ cause then there'd only be one generator of $D_n$ so my function has to be one that maps $(1,1) \mapsto r, (1,-1) \mapsto f, (1,-1)^k(1,1)^l \mapsto f^kr^l$ and the map I gave isn't very detailed just the one generator corresponds to a distinct generator of the other group. So $\phi((1,-1)^k(1,1)^l)=f^k \circ r^l = \phi((1,-1)^k) \circ \phi((1,1)^l, \forall k,l \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @SpamIAm I don't recognize the notation $\{\bar{0}, \bar{1}\}$

Comment: Fine $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \{0,1\}$.  The bars are just to remind you that these aren't the usual integers $0,1$ since $1 + 1 = 0$.

Comment: @SpamIAm oh okay, well then that would be $(1-,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ and under the operation I have on the first group $(-1,1)$ is the inverse of $(1,1)$. The mapping I gave is onto

Comment: You have written down a formula showing where a *general* element of the first group goes. Since $k$ only matters mod 2 in both the input and output, and every element of the first group is *uniquely* expressible as $(1,-1)^k(1,1)^l$ with $k$ determined mod 2, your definition on a *general* element (not just on generators) has been made. Now show your formula is a homomorphism (I am *not* saying this is going to be some kind of trivial matter; it takes patience).

Comment: ah I see, $k$ matters mod 2 because $(1,-1)^0 =e, (1,-1)^1 = (1,-1) \neq e$ the only options $\phi((1-1)^{k mod 2}(1,1)^l) = f^{k mod 2} \circ r^l = \phi((1,-1)^{k mod 2}) \circ \phi((1,1)^l), l, k \in \mathbb{N}$